# How to get index value in ng-template for primeng dropdown

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I am trying to get index value in ng-template for primeng dropdown but its giving me empty value. Here is sample code

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cards" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard">
 <ng-template let-card let-i="index" pTemplate="item">
  <span>{{i}}</span>
 </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you check primeng [source](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.ts#L22) code you will find that the pass the item of the passed options so there is no information about the index

```js
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: {$implicit: option}"></ng-container>
```

one way is to create a pipe the going to find the index base of the passed option

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'indexOf'
})
export class IndexOfPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items:any[] , item:any): any {
    return items.indexOf(item);
  }

}
```

*example*

```html
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" 
     optionLabel="name" [filter]="true" [showClear]="true"
    placeholder="Select a Country">

    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">

        <div>{{item.value.name}} {{cities | indexOf:item.value}} </div>

    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-mbnxin)

Answer (score 4):

You can try `<span>{{cards.indexOf(card)}}</span>`.

I think that `let-i="index"` within ng-template is not mentionned in primeng 9.x documentation.

Comment:  you are right about using the indexOf method of the passed option but you need to use pipe for it otherwise cards.indexOf(card) will run in every change detection and may case a pure performance

Comment: @malbarmavi Please correct me if I am wrong. I think after rendering the component if he removes one card from the middle of the array then the pipe will not detect the change for **cards**. So the solution doesn't support two-way binding right?

Answer (score 1):

Initiate the index As `rowIndex`

```
let-index="rowIndex"
```

And then use interpolation method

```
{{ index + 1 }}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it works for me, just use it like this :

`<ng-template let-i="rowIndex"> {{i}}  </ng-template>`

Answer (score 0):

`let-idx="index"` : Index of the current item : https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Solution:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cards" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard">
    <ng-template let-card let-idx="index" pTemplate="item">
        <span>{{idx}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Other usage exemple:

```
<div class="container">
    <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-idx="index">
        {{idx}}
    </ng-template>
</div>
```